# Is there a name for this function below?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, summation

I was wondering if there was a name for this function:

$$G(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_n^{jk}$$

for $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$, and where

$$w_n=e^{2i\pi/n}$$

In the case that $k$ is not a multiple of $n$, we have that $G(n,k)=0$.  But if $k$ is a multiple of $n$, say $k=an$, then $G(n,an)=a$.  I know its a finite geometric series, but I was wondering if had a reference associated with it.

Comment: Where did you see it? Whatever literature you saw it in might have a reference.

Comment: Playing around with generating functions for Euler numbers and analogues. It relates to series multisection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be in the form of the discrete Fourier transform of a constant.  I don't know if there is a special name for the case shown above, but you might find some clues based in the Fourier transform references:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform etc.  I hope this helps.